# phpdesktop laravel blank white page

Tags: php, laravel, desktop, phpdesktop

i need to make a website available offline, right off the bat my idea is to create a desktop app that would sync the database when connected to the server, then i came across phpdesktop, just tried using it for my brand new laravel project, but for some reason when i run the exe the only thing showed up is a blank white page. what seems to be the problem? the project is brand new

[image: screenshot white blank page]

the settings.json web_server is edited according to tutorials online :

```
{
    "web_server": {
        "listen_on": ["127.0.0.1", 0],
        "www_directory": "www/public",
        "index_files": ["index.php"],
        "cgi_interpreter": "php/php-cgi.exe",
        "cgi_extensions": ["php"],
        "cgi_temp_dir": "",
        "404_handler": "/index.php",
        "hide_files": []
    },
    "chrome": {
        "log_file": "debug.log",
        "log_severity": "default",
        "cache_path": "webcache",
        "external_drag": true,
        "external_navigation": true,
        "reload_page_F5": true,
        "devtools_F12": true,
        "remote_debugging_port": 0,
        "command_line_switches": {},
        "enable_downloads": true,
        "context_menu": {
            "enable_menu": true,
            "navigation": true,
            "print": true,
            "view_source": true,
            "open_in_external_browser": true,
            "devtools": true
        }
    }
}
```

log that comes out:

```
- 13:47:23.109 INFO: --------------------------------------------------------
- 13:47:23.109 INFO: Started application
- 13:47:23.109 INFO: Logging to: C:\phpdesktop-chrome-57.0-rc-php-7.1.3\debug.log
- 13:47:23.109 INFO: Log level = DEBUG4
- 13:47:23.109 INFO: Starting Mongoose 3.9c web server
- 13:47:23.109 INFO: WWW directory: C:\phpdesktop-chrome-57.0-rc-php-7.1.3\www\public
- 13:47:23.109 INFO: Index files: index.php
- 13:47:23.109 INFO: CGI interpreter: C:\phpdesktop-chrome-57.0-rc-php-7.1.3\php\php-cgi.exe
- 13:47:23.109 INFO: CGI pattern: **.php$
- 13:47:23.109 INFO: Hide files patterns:
- 13:47:23.109 DEBUG: The temp directory returned by OS contains unicode characters: C:\Users\KAMACH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\
- 13:47:23.125 INFO: CGI environment variables set: TMP=C:\WINDOWS\Temp,TEMP=C:\WINDOWS\Temp,TMPDIR=C:\WINDOWS\Temp,SERVER_NAME=127.0.0.1,PHPDESKTOP_VERSION=57.0
- 13:47:23.125 INFO: Web server url: http://127.0.0.1:51950/
- 13:47:23.140 INFO: remote_debugging_port = 54835
- 13:47:23.140 DEBUG: Command line string for the browser process: "C:\phpdesktop-chrome-57.0-rc-php-7.1.3\phpdesktop-chrome.exe" --no-sandbox --lang=en-US --log-file="C:\phpdesktop-chrome-57.0-rc-php-7.1.3\debug.log" --remote-debugging-port=54835 --disable-gpu
- 13:47:24.250 DEBUG: App::OnContextInitialized()
- 13:47:24.250 DEBUG: Window max width/height = 1286/720
- 13:47:24.265 DEBUG: GetBrowserWindow(): not found, hwnd = 5178660
- 13:47:24.265 DEBUG: WindowProc(): event WM_GETMINMAXINFO: could not fetch BrowserWindow
- 13:47:24.265 DEBUG: BrowserWindow::CreateBrowserControl()
- 13:47:24.265 DEBUG: StoreBrowserWindow(): hwnd = 5178660
- 13:47:24.328 DEBUG: ClientHandler::OnAfterCreated()
- 13:47:24.328 DEBUG: SetCefBrowser() called in ClientHandler::OnAfterCreated()
- 13:47:24.343 DEBUG: OnLoadingStateChange: loading=1, url=
- 13:47:25.843 INFO: GET 200 /
- 13:47:25.843 DEBUG: OnLoadingStateChange: loading=0, url=http://127.0.0.1:51950/
```

any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: just try     "www_directory": "/public" instead of   "www_directory": "www/public",

Comment: @Abdel-azizhassan just tried it, returned 404 not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update php from 7.1 to 7.2.19.
I find this repo https://github.com/laravelarticle/laravel-desktop and notice that this working on higher php.

Comment: you may also tell us why it is necessary to update the version of PHP.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know what is causing this.
I check different versions php on current phpdesctop and notice that this working repo use higher php.
https://github.com/laravelarticle/laravel-desktop

Comment: you may mention those references too. It would be a great help for someone.